# Unable to see list of emulator devices for Xamarin Android in VS 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am using VS 2015 enterprise update 3. After fresh installation, I created a new project--> cross platform tools--> Blank Xaml App(Xamarin.Forms Portable). then made Andriod project is default project from Solution explorer.
Tried select a device but none is available, altough when i open SDK Manager i can see 3 devices. 
[Andriod error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyK0Q.png)

[List of devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiCWJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your android project as your startup project?

[image: startup project]

Werid because in your screenshot it shows your portable project as your startup project. This is how it looks like when i debug my android project. 
[image: startup project]

Comment: checked  again, still  no luck. Same problem.

Comment: so i checked it again after your first reply. Even after as per your 2nd screenshot, get the same error.

Comment: Can you check your Android project settings, and check for your min and max api levels? Maybe those do not work with the installed emulators.

Comment: changed compile version to Android 6.0(Marshallow) and Minimum Android to target version to 4.0.3 ( Ice cream Sandwitch).  No luck yet!